# How to change the language and date format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, date-format

I am using SQL Server 2005. When I execute `DBCC USEROPTIONS`, I see the language as romana and dateformat as `dmy`.

I want the language to be `us_english` and dateformat as `mdy`.

How can I do this? I was having these settings initially but somehow they got changed to romana.

How to revert back to `us_english` and date as `dmy`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can reset the language by using the below syntax

```
set language 'us_english'
```

In order to view all the languages and their date format try this one

```
select * from sys.syslanguages
```

If you need to permanently change the language then

- Go To `Security`
- `Logins`
- Right Click on your username and select `Properties`
- Change the default language to `English`

This change will persist even after you restart your SSMS

Comment: praveenSet it just set the language for current session. When i disconnect from management studio and connect back . Now if i execute DBCC USEROPTIONS , i again see the language as romana instead of us_english

Comment: its already english there for all user including my user sa. But still dbcc operation returns as romana

Answer (score 8):

**Before**

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

is returning something like this:

[image: Current user options]

---

**To change** your or *UserLogin* configuration run:

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER LOGIN [UserLogin] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

Next - reconnect to SQL (*logout* -> *login*).

**After**

You will get this:

[image: Current user options]

Comment: To be even more precise you need to logout, close all script windows, login again. Each script window holds it's own connection to the server, so even if you logout you are still able to execute (eg) selects and the useroptions are still unchanged.