# How to change default language for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Now when I query

```
SELECT @@language
```

it gets 'us_english'. But I need russian.

I can't use `SET LANGUAGE russian` for every query.

I need to set it by default (for all new sessions).

Comment: If you want to set it globally for ever, look at [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220023/how-to-change-the-language-and-date-format-in-sql-server

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Using SQL Server Management Studio**

To configure the default language option

1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
2. Click the Misc server settings node.
3. In the Default language for users box, choose the language in which Microsoft SQL Server should display system messages.
   The default language is `English`.

**Using Transact-SQL**

To configure the default language option

1. Connect to the Database Engine.
2. From the Standard bar, click New Query.
3. Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click Execute.

This example shows how to use sp_configure to configure the default language option to *French*

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

- [Configure the default language Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190682.aspx#TsqlProcedure)

**The 33 languages of SQL Server**

```
| LANGID |        ALIAS        |
|--------|---------------------|
|    0   | English             |
|    1   | German              |
|    2   | French              |
|    3   | Japanese            |
|    4   | Danish              |
|    5   | Spanish             |
|    6   | Italian             |
|    7   | Dutch               |
|    8   | Norwegian           |
|    9   | Portuguese          |
|   10   | Finnish             |
|   11   | Swedish             |
|   12   | Czech               |
|   13   | Hungarian           |
|   14   | Polish              |
|   15   | Romanian            |
|   16   | Croatian            |
|   17   | Slovak              |
|   18   | Slovenian           |
|   19   | Greek               |
|   20   | Bulgarian           |
|   21   | Russian             |
|   22   | Turkish             |
|   23   | British English     |
|   24   | Estonian            |
|   25   | Latvian             |
|   26   | Lithuanian          |
|   27   | Brazilian           |
|   28   | Traditional Chinese |
|   29   | Korean              |
|   30   | Simplified Chinese  |
|   31   | Arabic              |
|   32   | Thai                |
|   33   | Bokmål              |
```

Comment: I got the opposite problem. A have @@LANGUAGE set to russian, and I want to change it to english. I have executed 
sp_configure 'default language', 0; 
And reconfigured. My default language is now set to English, BUT when I query SELECT @@LANGUAGE in a new query window, it still gets me russian. Is there something I forgot?

Comment: Oh, just figured out, that i must change it for SQL logins

Comment: How-to you get `33 languages list (full)` in **SQL Server** ?

Comment: Does changing the language changes the default date format `yyyy-MM-dd` used by SQL Server?

Comment: @Kiquenet : try sp_helplanguage

Comment: It;s not changing in sql server 2017 express. I tried multiple times even restarted machine multiple times. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Just a note on the script above: it does not set the language for the specified database; it changes _**the default for the instance itself**_, so please be careful. As pointed out by @ArsenMagomedov, the language for the database is actually defined on a user basis.

Comment: sp_helplanguage = select * from sys.syslanguages

Answer (score 33):

[John Woo's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706057/465053) has some caveats which you should be aware of:

1. **Default language** setting of a T-SQL session in SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) is inherited/overriden from/by **Default language** setting of the user login used to initiate the session instead. A new tab in SSMS creates a new T-SQL session. SQL Server instance level setting does *not* control the **Default language** setting of T-SQL session directly.
2. Changing **Default language** setting at SQL Server instance level has *no* effect on the **Default language** setting of the *already* existing SQL Server logins. It is meant to be inherited only by the new user logins that we create *after* changing the instance level setting. So don't be surprised if you changed the **Default language** setting at SQL Server instance level but it didn't take effect for your user account. It is as per design.

So, there is an intermediate configuration level between SQL Server instance level and the T-SQL session level. It is called **user login level**. You can use this intermediate level configuration to control the **Default language** setting for T-SQL session without disrupting the SQL Server instance level settings.

```text
    SQL Server Instance level setting
                 |
                 V
    
    User login level setting
                 |
                 V
    
    T-SQL Query Session level setting
```

This intermediate level setting is very helpful in case you want to set **Default language** setting to some value for all *new* T-SQL sessions(tabs in SSMS) belonging to some specific user.

We can change the **Default language** setting of the target user login as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql) link. You can also achieve it from SSMS console e.g. we can change the **Default language** setting from the properties window of **sa** user in SQL Server via SSMS (Refer screenshot):

[image]

**Note**: Changing the setting at user login level will *not* affect the setting of already active tabs in SSMS. It will affect only the *new* tabs which will be opened after changing the setting.

Comment: Awesome, I was running out of resources to solve this same problem, thanks for this info!

Comment: This should be the correct answer for this question.

Comment: I love you!  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Please try below:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME;  
SET @Today = '12/5/2007';  

SET LANGUAGE Italian;  
SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name';  

SET LANGUAGE us_english;  
SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name' ;  
GO
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of just posting a code block, you should provide an explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change MSSQL server language, you can use the following QUERY:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 'British English';
```

Comment: This answer needs more of an explanation; the OP asked how to change the language on a database level, not the default for the instance, which is what you've specified.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer OP's question, this extra bit of info was really useful. set language 'British English' works for TSQL. I'd been searching and tried UK, GB, "international", all to no avail. This is what I needed. So whilst I can't give an upvote - I've said thanks with the applause button (I know - I hate myself).