# DATEFORMAT FUNCTION IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql, I am in trouble with date formats I know I can use cast or convert function but I was looking to dateformat (we use format dd/mm/yy). I looks quite interesting function and very easy but there is a problem.
IF I run this dataview

```
SELECT     hotel, id, codicecliente, prodotto, CAST(REPLACE(numeros, ',', '.') AS decimal(7, 2)) AS numero, CAST(REPLACE(importos, ',', '.') AS decimal(7, 2)) AS importo, 
                      CAST(datas AS datetime) AS data, puntovendita, DATEDIFF(day, '01/01/2000', datas) AS datav, isdate(datas) AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.addebititmp
WHERE     (isdate(datas) = 1)
```

it shows me about 15.000 records it is not showing all record with data with day more than 12 because system recognizes first 2 as month not day
if I add  SET DATEFORMAT dmy
and run the following

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

SELECT     hotel, id, codicecliente, prodotto, CAST(REPLACE(numeros, ',', '.') AS decimal(7, 2)) AS numero, CAST(REPLACE(importos, ',', '.') AS decimal(7, 2)) AS importo, 
                      CAST(datas AS datetime) AS data, puntovendita, DATEDIFF(day, '01/01/2000', datas) AS datav, isdate(datas) AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.addebititmp
WHERE     (isdate(datas) = 1)
```

It shows correctly all 38.000 records but when I save the view system shows error: incorrect syntax near the keyword set. So I can run but not use it. I tried also with transact sql but if I creat a view with dateformat it does not save the dateformat and shows less records.
Any suggestion? Thank You

Comment: Use `'yyyymmdd'` (e.g. '20141122'). It works the same regardless of dateformat setting.

Comment: To summarize your question. You want to use ISDATE() in WHERE class for date format (dd/mm/yy). But you was unable to do it. Also you don't want to use convert inside ISDATE(). Because it may throw unwanted exception while converting non date values and SELECT query may fail. Am I correct?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2012 or 2014, you can use [`TRY_CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993(v=sql.110).aspx) instead of `ISDATE()` or `TRY_PARSE()` with a defined language that uses `dd/mm/yy` format.

Comment: Yes Veera you're correct, if I use isdate in where class using date format dd/mm/yy I lose data so I should convert before but if I convert I get an exception if I use try_convert as Bacon suggests I lose data because if data is 31/12/2014 I lose it, why dateformat can't be saved in a view? This would solve easily, It's weird I can execute but not save. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error when creating the view with `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` is due to a view being an encapsulation of a single query, not multiple commands. If you need multiple commands, then you would have to use a Multistatement Table-Valued Function. But using a TVF is not necessary here.

Use [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) as it will handle both the translation and the "ISDATE" behavior. It will either convert to a proper DATETIME or it will return NULL. In this sense, a non-NULL value equates to ISDATE returning 1 while a NULL value equates to ISDATE returning 0. Since your data is in the format of DD/MM/YYYY, that is the "style" number 103 (full list of Date and Time styles found on the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) MSDN page).

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, tmp.DateDDMMYYYY, 103) AS [ConvertedDate],
       tmp.ShouldItWork
FROM (
   VALUES('23/05/2014', 'yes'),
         ('05/23/2014', 'no'),
         ('0a/4f/2014', 'no')
 ) tmp(DateDDMMYYYY, ShouldItWork);
```

Results:

```
ConvertedDate            ShouldItWork
2014-05-23 00:00:00.000  yes
NULL                     no
NULL                     no
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are probably Italian??  If so, you should change your default language to Italian on the server.  This will also by default change your DATEFORMAT to accept European-style dates.  I am assuming all your char-formatted dates will be stored in that format?  This will show you how:

[How to change default language for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705983/how-to-change-default-language-for-sql-server)

Also, regarding saving the dateformat setting in the view, you can't save it in a view for the same reason you can't save "set nocount on" in a view.  But you can set the dateformat in a stored proc that references the view.  But I really think in your case you should set the server-wide language, which will address the issue.

Comment: Changing default language does not fix it and the problem is I should rewrite many queries which work on english format on this server (for number conversion for istance). Store procedure is a good idea but I should rewrite vb.net to get data from datareader any idea for the view?

Comment: Try this: SET LANGUAGE Italian;  SELECT ISDATE('15/2/2014');  You will see that SQL Server now sees it as a valid date.  Now you just have to set the Language setting server-wide (you should research it more if you are having problems).  It will work.  Try reading this:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907

Answer (score 0):

Kevin your solution is not working for me. 
Solved this way
Create this function and use as I wish on view
I suggest to leave it as nvarchar instead of date to control all data in the view.

-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION fdataitaineng
(
    -- Questa funzione trasforma da formato italiano ad inglese
    @datas nvarchar (12)
)
RETURNS nvarchar (12)
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @datan as nvarchar(12)
```

select @datan=SUBSTRING(@datas, 4, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@datas, 1, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@datas, 7, 4)

```
RETURN @datan
```

END
GO

Comment: Please do not use a T-SQL User-Defined Function for this. It is horribly inefficient and unnecessary since a built-in function already exists that does this (and more). Please see my answer.