# Set localization of SQL Server messages in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, localization, extract-error-message

I'm developing a Windows app in Visual Studio 2012. It opens connection to SQL Server.

`app.config` is set to use `en-US` for exception messages and it works:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="DefaultCulture" value="en-US"/>
    ...
</appSettings>
```

But when SQL Server throws an exception, its message isn't in English.

How can I, from C#, tell SQL Server, to send me proper messages?

Comment: is your DB default language other?

Comment: Why do you care? Exception messages are for developers, and should not be visible to the users anyway...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705983/how-to-change-default-language-for-sql-server But this seem will stay in config, Seem cannot change language dynamically

Comment: The MSSQL server I use unfortunately is configured for portuga... portuga error messages are hard to find on Google and very badly translated, I hardly understand what they mean.

Comment: I care... because I'm developer? Because I must see what's wrong to fix it?