# Default Culture Used by SQL Server For Parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the following statement:

```
SELECT CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
```

I get the 1988-12-08, not 1988-08-12 in ISO 8601 format. How does SQL Server decide which format to apply for parsing? I know the best practices, I'm just interested in where does it take it and how it can be changed?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a "culture", it will just always parse a value in that format as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: So, SQL Server just has some predefined sense (so to speak) of input formats, right?

Comment: @DavidG, that's not entirely correct. You can set the dateformat using `SET DATEFORMAT ydm` to use a format like `1990/31/12` (as an example). I don't know if you can set the separators as well.

Comment: @HoneyBadger oh, thanks for the clarification. But nevertheless, is it true that SQL Server defines some default formats? And SET DATEFORMAT works per session?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Hmm yes, I'll add that to my answer

Comment: @EngineerSpock, both statements are correct. `SET DATEFORMAT` is connection dependent. You can also set the default during installation.

Comment: There are only 2 formats that SQL Server will correctly parse, no matter the collation... YYYY-MM-DD & YYYYMMDD... Every other format will have some dependancy of the collation being used.

Comment: While `set dateformat` is limited to the current connection, you can create a login to always use a specific language setting: `ALTER LOGIN your_login WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=British`. You can even add your own language by using `exec sp_addlanguage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First.. Format for parsing dates is based on an environment language currently set in the active session. You can see the current language with `SELECT @@LANGUAGE` and you can change it using [SET LANGUAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql) command.

Next you can override the format of current language by setting your own date format with [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql). However, mind that if you change language again, it overrides the format settings.

Here are few examples on how different settings behave and affect your CAST query:

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
, CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
, DATENAME(month,CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE)) AS MonthName; 

SET LANGUAGE English
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
, CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
, DATENAME(month,CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE)) AS MonthName; 

SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
, CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
, DATENAME(month,CAST ('12/08/1988' AS DATE)) AS MonthName;
```

Default language setting for each new query is set on login level. You can change it by finding in Object Explorer on *server->Logins->YourLogin->Properties->Default Language* or with `ALTER LOGIN` command

Further, there is also a default language on server, which affects default choice for newly created logins.

More about that you can find in this question: 
[How to change default language for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705983/how-to-change-default-language-for-sql-server)

At the end, like others said, you should avoid confusion by using [CONVERT with style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), ISO format and appropriate data types.

My tips: 
If you want to convert string to date in adhoc queries (like in example), always use ISO format and there is no need to worry about format and not even a need to convert:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateColumn = '20170325'
```

If you want to convert date to string (for display) use CONVERT with desired style:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), DateColumn, 104) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't have a "culture", it will just always parse a value in that format as `mm/dd/yyyy` (i.e. US format). you can control it to some degree using [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql), for example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
```

However, these are fairly basic formats and you really should avoid relying on them.

If you want to change it, you should use the `CONVERT` function, or the newer [`PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql). For example, to specify British format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '12/08/1988', 103)
```

Or:

```
SELECT PARSE('12/08/1988' AS DATETIME USING 'en-GB')
```

Comment: this is not really correct, each login has a default language which is used to format dates, you can always choose language different than English to be default.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will always be more reliable, regardless of date formats:

```
SELECT CAST ('1988-08-12' AS DATE) AS BIRTHDAY
```

As you're not specifying the format, it will use default date format on your SQL instance, which looks like English US.