# SSIS - Date conversion Date formatting MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting confusion when loading data from staging to target for the date column by using ssis as ETL tool.
Staging:

```
varchar (datatype)-'09/05/2017'
```

Target:
conversion transformation is used to convert to date datatype.Now records like
`09/05/2017`.
But while loading to final table Record is like `2017-09-05 00:00:00` which is datetime datatype.

Actual expected result:`2017-05-09 00:00:00`

Note:OTHER records are inserted with correct format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Culture Used by SQL Server For Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508704/default-culture-used-by-sql-server-for-parsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSIS - The `LocaleID` property of your DataFlow components handle whether dates are parsed into `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`.

[image]

In SQL - A similar thing is handled by the [SET LANGUAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql) command.

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '1929/12/18'

SET LANGUAGE british
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '1929/12/18' -- fails
```

Check your settings in both SQL and SSIS.  Adjust if necessary.

Comment: @thanks for the help troy ....I have changed the setting,Now it is working fine..