# SQL Server changing date format to accept d/m/y

Tags: sql-server

An application is passing the below query to the SQL server and I'm receiving an exception from SQL server as *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

```
update Images set  Created_DATE='23/09/2020 11:00:09'
 where ID = 10
```

Additionally, I cant see the below error in Profiler.

[image]

What I've tried is,

1. Changes the Date format of SQL server as DMY
2. Change the language to en-GB

I can't change the code so how to make this work by changing SQL server configuration?

Comment: You do not need that double quotes.

Comment: And use the convert function if still required.

Comment: If you can’t change the code and is about SQLServer configuration, why is this tagged as C# and .NET?

Comment: First thing I would do, to ask people who wrote that application, to pass the date as `DateTime`, not `string`.

Comment: If you have no way to change code, you can do several things, first thing comes in mind, is... for example if you have a table called MyTable, then create table MyTable_2 (name it whatever you prefer), create a trigger on MyTable insert and convert that `string` date to `datetime` and insert it to MyTable_2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update Images 
set  Created_DATE=CONVERT(DATETIME, N'23/09/2020 11:00:09', 103) 
where ID = 10
```

You need to convert the string to date setting a culture. Otherwise, the engine is not able to understand the format as there are various [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

I believe, your date type is `DATETIME`, and that's why you are getting this error:

```
SELECT CAST('23/09/2020 11:00:09' AS DATETIME);
```

result as:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4 The conversion of a varchar data
> type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

for `DATETIME2` it is:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

Comment: The problem is the query is coming from an application and I can't change the application code. Can it be handled in SQL server by making some config changes or by triggers?

Comment: @Jay, No, you cannot use a trigger. You can change the default language - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706057/1080354

Comment: It is British English but still getting the error though the dateformat of British English is D/M/Y

Comment: So, if you execute the code as I have shown in the answer in the SQL Server Management Studio you are still getting an error?

Comment: I know the convert function will make this work. My question is I cant change the query as it comes from application and wants to make this work by changing culture language etc..

Comment: @Jay, I mean, can you test this? `SET LANGUAGE British;

SELECT CAST(N'23/09/2020 11:00:09' AS DATETIME);
`

Comment: This works in SSMS but when I get that query from application, it throws an error

Comment: Any thoughts, i can see the cast function works after changing the language in SSMS. But when query comes from external application it still fails with the same error

Comment: Well, the application code itself can be setting a language. You can create a trigger to record the current language using `SELECT @@language` and check if your database settings is overwritten. Also, in the SSMS, if you just execute in a new query window `SELECT CAST(N'23/09/2020 11:00:09' AS DATETIME);` - is this still working?

Comment: It looks like application not overwriting anything and cast query still works in SSMS. But in profiler I can see an error message an shown in the question. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I can see the below in profiler when I start.Later it tries to change to british english it seems..../////////
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7

Comment: @Jay, the profiler is showing this as error but it is not - `It looks like all infoMessage tokens are handled as User Error Message in SQL Profiler.` https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/101

Comment: Also in profiler i can see the language changing automatically. It changes after exec sp_reset_connection  and it is automatically switching from English to British English and Vice versa. As a result when application send the query the language changes to English and query fails

Comment: Just for the test, can you change the column data type to `VARCHAR(18)` and see how exactly the sent value looks like.

Comment: It comes as 23/09/2020 13:01:55