# SQL Server 2017 Express, unable to change datetime format from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Installed Sql Server 2017 Express on Azure VM and wanted to change datetime format from `MM/dd/YYYY` to `dd/MM/YYYY` so for that I changed default language from `us_english` to `British`.

**Edit:** I am passing some dates from my application to database in DD/MM/YYYY format and database is not accepting because database has set for MM/DD/YYYY format (US format)

I tried multiple ways but none is working.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23 ; 
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

and tried this also [How to change the language and date format in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220023/how-to-change-the-language-and-date-format-in-sql-server) but result is same.

[image]

Advance tab is although shows British but Datetime format is still `MM/DD/YYY`
[image]

Comment: Date time format of what?

Comment: Database server. I am passing some dates from my application to database in DD/MM/YYYY format and database is not accepting because database has set for MM/DD/YYYY format (US format)

Comment: Data is stored in binary format in the system. You need to specify the data format while selecting the data. Please re-organize your query to get the time in correct format.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store dates in format; it stores them as binary values. If you're *displaying* the value and it's in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` it's the application that is the problem. If you're using a query like `SELECT CONVERT(date,'14/08/2019')` and getting a conversion error the problem is 2 fold; you're not using an unambiguous format (use `yyyyMMdd`) and the language of the **Login** is likely American English.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged Windows Server 2008, when the screenshot clearly shows Windows Server 2016 DataCentre?

Comment: And that indicates you are not properly parameterizing your tsql statements from your application. Fix that. Perhaps this is due to [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Please check question again, I updated it. @Larnu because solution suppose to be common

Comment: Common to what? Don't tag things that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: common to all windows versions.

Comment: `I am passing some dates from my application to database in DD/MM/YYYY format` ... just stop doing this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand cannot at this point of time and same thing is working fine on my AWS instance but not sure what's wrong in newly configured azure instance.

Comment: "I don't want to do things right, I just want to patch my kludge." If you fix your app so it passes unambiguous dates, it will now work on any Azure instance and it will also keep working on your AWS instance.

Comment: stop passing date times in a format that is not region independant, see [this](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the language of the database, or the Server, it's of the login.

You either need to provide the dates in an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss`) or change the language of the login:

```
ALTER LOGIN YourLogin WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = BRITISH;
```

Comment: ...of _all_ relevant logins, which makes the unambiguous format much more sensible.

Comment: I feel suggesting all logins could be an unsafe assumption, as we don't if the OP's instance is used my many users with different geographical locations, @AaronBertrand . Of course, really, they should be writing code that is language agnostic.

Comment: Well I think it is implied that it's all logins that could possibly use this application. If the application is (or all applications are) hard-coding this bad format...

Comment: I tried already, it suppose to work but not working. not sure why

Comment: @JitendraPancholi You need to close *all* connections for the altered login before it takes affect (that includes all open query windows in SSMS)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Just stop passing dates to SQL Server in a specific, regional format. Use one that isn't affected by regional settings, language on the server, language on the instance, language of the login...

Comment: @JitendraPancholi and well, yeah what Aaron said - passing regional-formatted dates to databases is the headache that keeps on giving. Wherever humanly possible use ISO format and the headache goes away.

Comment: Same thing is working fine on my AWS instance and I did the same thing there too. Not sure what's wrong here in azure.

Comment: This all reminds me of a conversation I had with a vendor a few weeks back, where when we installed the app I explicitly asked "does your service account require a specific language?", To which I was told "no, it doesn't matter"; so I set it to our default (British). 10 minutes later the app fell over with it error log full of conversion errors as it was using `MM/DD/yyyy`.... Vendor got a few choice words on their design choices and and lack of knowledge of the importance of language settings...

Comment: @Larnu how did you fix that problem then?

Comment: and how did you set your default to British?

Comment: With the above code, @JitendraPancholi against the service account.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give your languages available in Your Database...For Eg. English,German...etc..

**select * from sys.syslanguages**

Set Your language as your preference

**SET LANGUAGE English**

Comment: "English" isn't English on SQL Server (or any Microsoft product), it's American and uses the date format `MM/dd/yyyy`. Microsoft refers to English (the language those located in England/UK speak) as British or "English International".